# how to split up common github actions in common files?

Tags: unit-testing, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

So following this guide:  https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-25-github-actions-reduce-duplication-with-action-composition/

And looking at my 1st github action to run unit tests on a node API (the ssh stuff there is due to the projects sharing a few common modules installed from our orgs github via ssh references, if there is a simpler method I would love to know it):

```
name: Node.js API

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
      - master

env:
  TEST_MONGO_HOST: ${{ secrets.TEST_MONGO_HOST }}
  TEST_MONGO_PW: ${{ secrets.TEST_MONGO_PW }}
  TEST_MONGO_PORT: ${{ secrets.TEST_MONGO_PORT }}
  TEST_MONGO_PROTOCOL: ${{ secrets.TEST_MONGO_PROTOCOL }}
  TEST_MONGO_USER: ${{ secrets.TEST_MONGO_USER }}
  TEST_MONGO_ADDITIONAL_PARAMS: ${{ secrets.TEST_MONGO_ADDITIONAL_PARAMS }}

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup SSH Keys and known_hosts
        run: |
          mkdir ~/.ssh
          touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          touch ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          touch ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
          echo "${{ secrets.GH_ACTION_GH_KNOWN_HOSTS }}" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          echo "${{ secrets.GH_ACTION_GH_KEY_PRIVATE }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          echo "${{ secrets.GH_ACTION_GH_KEY_PUBLIC }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
          chmod 700 ~/.ssh
          chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ secrets.NODE_VERSION }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ secrets.NODE_VERSION }}
          cache: 'npm'
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
      - run: npm run test
```

If it understood this correctly, I should be able to place the above action somewhere and then only add this to each service?

```
on: [push]

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: my-org/npmi-build-test@v1
```

Assuming this is correct, does the "common" file need its own repository or is there a "action registry" somewhere I am missing? Or if a special github repo is needed is this then 1 repo per action or is there a naming convention to follow?

Answer (score 0):

In your shared workflow, you need to add the trigger `workflow_call`. The triggers `push` and `pull_request` are not needed there, unless you want to also trigger that workflow when someone pushes to that repository.

The shared workflow can go into its own repository or be in the same as the workflow that is triggered e.g. by a push.

The shared workflow is reference not only with the repository name, but also with the filename.

Assuming that your shared workflow is in a repository called `my-org/workflows` and in a file called `.github/workflows/tests.yml`, then you can reference it like so:

```yaml
jobs:
  test:
    uses: my-org/workflows/.github/workflows/tests.yml@main
```

Note that this also assumes there is a branch (or tag) called `main`.

Comment: wow that answer is so much clearer than their own docs thank you! using the key "workflow_call" I then landed here https://github.blog/2022-02-10-using-reusable-workflows-github-actions/ too - thanks for the answer! very clear

Comment: If the repo is shared - do you know if there is any reason to not place simplify the path to " uses: my-org/workflows/tests.yml@main"

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#access-to-reusable-workflows  damn there are wildly crazy limitations.. i think we might have to move to gitlab instead

Comment: "Reusable workflows stored within a private repository can only be used by workflows within the same repository." this effectively means we can not use them.. the public repo can be read but doesn't have access to the env. vars set by the private repo.